# How to change the color of a TextView in one activity by clicking a button in another?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview

I have two activities, in activity(1) I have a TextView, in activity(2) I have a button. I want to change the TextView color in activity(1) by clicking the button in activity(2) and save this color. How can I do this?

Comment: So I guess activity1 launches activity2?

Comment: No, I have 1 activity that launches 4 other activities and these 2 activities are launches by 1 main activity

Comment: you can use the shared preferences to save the value of color and then use it

Comment: yeah then other suggestions about using database or Shared Preferences will suit your case here

Comment: How can I do this?? I tried, but I couldn't do this

Comment: shared preference is best for you try this

Comment: If you are coming back to the textview activity after clicking button in another activity then you can startActivityForResult()

Answer (score 3):

You can save your color with Shared Preferences when your button is clicked and later get it :

**In activity 2 when your button is pressed** :

```
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this)
        .edit()
        .putString(key, value).apply();
```

**And in activity 1 get the value that you saved:**

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(DriverScreen.this).getString(key, "default value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a database for keep the textview color and get the color from database. when click the button you can change it in the database.

Comment: He can use Shared Preferences  , database is not his only option

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to your problem

1. You can use sharepreference.
2. You can use a singleton class.
3. You can use a eventlistener.
4. You can use intent.putExtra() for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

there will be many ways to achieve what you want, use one of them as per your choice.

**To store text color :**

1. Use SharedPreference
2. Use Room or SQLite Database
3. Save color in Singleton class
4. or open second activity using startActivityForResult() if you're coming back to 1st activity after completion of 2nd activity work.

**To Change Text Color:**

1. Use Listener to change text color when you press button from 2nd activity
2. Use EventBus if you already have implemented it in your project
3. Using Local Broadcast Receiver (Send broadcast to 1st activity after click on button of 2nd activity)

Answer (score 0):

there is many ways to change text color from another activity.

**First**

pass color value using intent

**Code**

`Main2Activity.java`

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int color=getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
            Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("color",color);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
  android_text=findViewById(R.id.android_text);
    color=getIntent().getIntExtra("color",0);
    android_text.setTextColor(color);
```

**Second way**

use static variable

**code**

`MainActivity.java`

```
  static int color;
    android_text=findViewById(R.id.android_text);
    android_text.setTextColor(color);
```

`Main2Activity.java`

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //set color
            MainActivity.color=getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
            Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

[image]

**after update**

[image]

I Hope its work for you